# Dynamic length string array

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, file-io

I an a newbie to c++.
I want to write a program to read values from file which has data in format:

```
text<tab or space>text
text<tab or space>text
...
```

(... indicates more such lines)

The number of lines in file **varies**. Now, I want to read this file and store the text into either 1 2D string array or 2 1D string arrays.
How do I do it?

Furthermore, I want to run a for loop over this array to process the each entry in file. How can I write that loop?

Comment: What research have you done so far to tackle the problem? Have you searched the site? This is a very common task.

Comment: Before you even go about doing what Matthias said, what do you actually do with these arrays? Sometimes we may overlook at arrays and its usefulness.

Comment: When I wrote the question, I saw all the similar question that appear on right side. And none of them solved my problem. Anyways, I'll try to find similar question.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a resizable array. Try `std::vector<string>`. You can find documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/).

Edit: You could probably also manage to do this by opening the file, looping through to count the lines of the file, generating your fixed-size array, closing and reopening the file, and then looping through the file to populate the array. However, this is not recommended, as it will increase your runtime complexity far more than the slight overhead involved with managing vector, and it will make your code much more confusing for anyone who reads it.

(ps - I agree with @matthias-vallentin, you should've been able to find this on the site with minimal work)